# How to use Veeam to recover locally-hosted Exchange mailbox alias to implement on Exchange Online

Tags: active-directory, exchange, alias, mailbox, veeam

I've inherited an IT department after just 1 year in it, during which the 30-year sole-IT person retired, and his replacement, who hired me, left for a remote position.  Shortly before he left, Veeam was implemented as our backup solution, and we moved our on-premise Exchange server to Exchange Online.  I realized too late (after our consultant guided me to remove Exchange from both local servers) that aliases on the on-premise Exchange server never migrated to their respective accounts on EO.  However, the Veeam service backed up our on-premise Exchange server, so I have access to the files from that system.  Can I get information on the aliases so that I can re-implement them in AD and have them populate in EO, preferably without restoring the mail server entirely?

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem -- email aliases are stored in the "ProxyAddresses" attribute of the object in Active Directory.  Can you not just view the aliases on the object?  If the recipients were deleted, can you not just restore them from the AD Recycle Bin and then view the attributes?

Comment: Why are you looking to restore an Exchange server from a backup?  The Exchange Server doesn't house a directory or objects -- that's what Active Directory is for; that is why Active Directory is required for an Exchange installation.

Comment: Proxy addresses are an attribute of the user account, not the mailbox, the mailbox database, or the Exchange server... so restoring your on premises Exchange server is unlikely to help and would be potentially counter-productive.

Comment: What you could probably do, if you have a backup of AD and Exchange, is to restore a backup of both to an isolated network and then grab the proxy addresses of the users. Then add those in O365.

Comment: Second to @joeqwerty comment. I would do the same, and export those proxyaddresses individually, and add them to the EO afterwards

Comment: AD hasn't changed.  Only the Exchange servers were decommissioned.  If, as you say, all aliases can only be proxyaddresses on the AD accounts, why have they not migrated with the rest of AD?  There has to be some part of Exchange that stored those aliases separately from AD, or they would still be there.

Answer (score 0):

The Exchange servers are store the mailboxes data not AD accounts/aliases. As everyone mentioned, you should restore AD. And it is better to restore both AD and Exchange servers, because it will be more convenient for migrating to Exchange Online from Exchange servers.